# Having trouble decoding json in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to insert an array of 3 digit integers into a MySQL Database (e.g. '301', '302' etc). The array is passed using jQuery, Ajax and JSON into the PHP script. This bit (judging by the 'console.log' function) seems to work fine. The problem comes at the other end when I try to decode the JSON string.

I want each individual item in the array to go into a separate column, but at the moment all that is being inserted into the column is the number '0'.

Code is as follows:

jQuery:

```
var modules

$('#createbutton').click(function(){
 $('#l3 :checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
  var l3modules = $(this).attr('value');
  modules.push(l3modules);
  });

var modulestransmit = JSON.stringify(modules);
console.log(modulestransmit);

$.ajax({
       url: "newaccount.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { modules: modulestransmit },
     });
 });
```

PHP:

```
 $modules = $_REQUEST['modulestransmit']);
 $insertmodules = json_decode($modules, true);

 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO level3 (mod1, mod2) VALUES ('$insertmodules[0]', '$insertmodules[1]')")) {
  echo "Successfully inserted";
 }
 else {
  echo "Insertion Failed";
 }
```

The result in the database is:

mod1:   0

mod2:   0

Comment: try using `var_dump($insertmodules)` to have a look at the variable and make sure it is what you expect it is !

Comment: In JS you add the data param `modules`, while from PHP you retrieve something called `modulestransmit`.

Comment: not an answer to you question, but you NEVER should use data you receive from external source in your SQL queries without escaping them. otherwise SQL injections can be done.

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually removed the escape code to keep things looking simple, but appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using modules as the name of the parameter in the request not modulestransmit so change the first line of your PHP to

```
 $modules = $_REQUEST['modules'];
```

and you also need to put curly braces around the variable names in the string (vital when referencing arrays in double quotes in PHP).

```
"INSERT INTO level3 (mod1, mod2) VALUES ('{$insertmodules[0]}', '{$insertmodules[1]}')"
```

and that should do it.

Comment: shouldn't this brutally explode because of that not being a legal identifier?

Comment: referencing  $modules = $_REQUEST['modulestransmit']); when it doesn't exist should cause a syntax error but none is mentioned in the OP's question.  It certainly would explain why things weren't working but I'm surprised he didn't see it blow up when he tried to run the code.

Comment: I tend to assume those kinds of errors creep in as typos when people post/retype code. But, good point.

EDIT: I initially thought you meant my code!

Comment: Hi all, have tried updating this but still getting the same result. Any more ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: airza, actually, it's PHP and it's and array, so if the key doesn't exist it returns null.

Chris, you might also need curly braces around the variable names in the SQL string... I'll put it in my post.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but it still seems to be doing the same. If it helps, running a var_dump($insertmodules) is coming up as NULL and a var_dump($modules) returns: string(17) "[\"301\",\"303\"]", so it looks like the issue is something to do with the json_decode

Comment: what about var_dump($insertmodules) ?

Comment: var_dump($insertmodules) returns NULL

Comment: AHA! IT's the escapes! If I vardump that text I get string(13) "["301","303"]" back, so the backslashes are actually there and not escape chars.

Comment: My web hosts use either PHP 4.4.8 or 5.2.5 - I'm trying to find out which version is activated but it's not easy to find!

Comment: Sorry I just edited rather than posting a new comment, see my previous comment for the answer. Your PHP version will be 5.2.5 as json_decode didn't exist before 5.2

Comment: So how do I remove the escapes from the string? If it helps, the array integers are generated from a javascript loop collecting values from a group of checkboxes (you can see this in the original code).

Comment: Never mind - I figured this part out (stripslashes). Thanks for all your help!!